# Windows Subsystem for Linux: /home/user (Linux Home Directory Path) to use for ConEmu Terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

#### I'm trying to set up 2 terminal location tabs to open in my [ConEmu Terminal](http://conemu.github.io/) on Windows 10 (for Windows Linux Subysystem)

---

**1. Windows Home Directory**

```
C:\Users\USERNAME
    or...
%USERPROFILE%
```

and

**2. Linux Home Directory**

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Lxss\home\USERNAME
       or...
%LOCALAPPDATA%\lxss\home\USERNAME
```

The Window Home path works fine, but I'm not sure how to make the Linux Home path work? The closest I can get is to making it open up the root `/` location.

Does anyone know the right way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I stumbled upon the article "[Bashing Windows](https://www.herebedragons.io/bashing-windows)" *(By: Jan De Dobbeleer)*,
 
which led me to this answer.

The main trick is the `~` *(tilde)* when opening the bash shell.

---

## Home (Linux)

- BASH (path): `C:\Windows\System32\Bash.exe ~` *(has tilde ~)*
- STARTUP DIRECTORY (path): `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\lxss\home`

---

## Root (Linux)

- BASH (path): `C:\Windows\System32\Bash.exe` *(no tilde)*
- STARTUP DIRECTORY (path): `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\lxss\root`

---

## Home (Windows)

- BASH (path): `C:\Windows\System32\Bash.exe` *(no tilde)*
- STARTUP DIRECTORY (path): `C:\Users\<YourUserName>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if things have changed, but the command I needed to launch ConEmu into my linux subsystem's home directory is:

`%windir%\system32\bash.exe ~ -new_console:d:C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\lxss\home`

[image]